# Get data from Subject instantly before page render

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular 8 application I have Auth service, where I get user data to a Subject:

```
export class AuthService {
   userSource: Subject<any> = new Subject()
   user = this.userSource.asObservable()
}

constructor() {
   this.authState.subscribe(user => {
     this.userSource.next(user)
   })
}
```

And in all my components, where I need user data I get them in next way:

```
// Component

user

constructor(auth: AuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.auth.userSource.subscribe(user => {
     this.user = user
   })
}
```

And this is work, but before the component displays user data, it takes about a second. Can it be done instantly?

Comment: If you need to get that data BEFORE your app bootrstrap you should use an APP_INITIALIZER token, it runs a function before your app bootstraps, so you got your auth data ready when your component load https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: Another option is a route resolver. The route resolver will ensure data is retrieved before navigating to a route or set of routes.

Comment: If you put a `console.log` just after you set `this.user`, does that show up before the component updates?

Comment: @Vlad274 after ~1 sec

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk the log message is displayed in the console ~1 second before the component updates?